# What might prevent dlls to be loaded from system32?

Tags: windows, dll

I have an application that reads some dlls from system32 which is put there when the application is installed.

On some machines the application runs fine but on others it never starts (because the dlls cannot be loaded). What might prevent an application from reading dlls from system32 (eg. messing around with the PATH variable etc)?

It can be solved by putting the dlls next to the exe file, but it could be nice to understand why some machines (only installed on windows 7 machines) can start the application while other cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 64-bit version of Windows for example.  32-bit DLLs should go in c:\windows\syswow64.  Using the operating system folders for your own DLLs is not recommended.